# Nodejs and mssql datetime input params

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I'm having troubles querying a sql server function which requires two datetime params.

If I call it in the Sql managment studio it works but if I execute the SAME code in node it does not work.

I have tried so many ways of doing it but I can't make it work.

Tha mssql version I'm using is: `"mssql": "^5.1.0"`

The error I always get is:
`Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

One of the sql query is:
`SELECT * FROM dbo.Festadisticalb_2017(@inidate,@findate)`

I have also tried with `CONVERT` and `CAST` without success.

I also tried:

```
queryreppedidos =
  "DECLARE @inidate as date;" +
  "SET @inidate = DATEADD(DAY, -500, GETDATE());" +
  "DECLARE @findate as date;" +
  "SET @findate = GetDate();" +
  "SELECT TOP 10 fe.NumeroDocumento, fe.Cant_Pedida, fe.Descripcion, " +
  "fe.Observacion, fe.Pedido_LB, fe.Referencia, fe.Responsable, " +
  "fe.OC_Cliente, fe.Cliente, fe.Linea, fe.Valor_Pedido, fe.Transito_Total, " +
  "fe.Orden_Fabrica, fe.Proveedor, fe.Importacion, " +
  "fe.Stock, fe.Terceros, fe.Pendientes, fe.Transito, fe.PorComprar, fe.Estado, " +
  "fe.Asesor FROM dbo.Festadisticalb_2017(@inidate,@findate) fe " +
  "WHERE fe.Responsable = 'SRR';";
```

The thing is: How to correctly write the datetime input params in order to successfully query a function using `mssql` in `nodejs`?

Thanks for your support. Have a great day.

Comment: Without the SQL you're using, the node.js code and with no sample data, how do you propose we help you here..?

Comment: Hi, I wrote some sample queries I'm trying. Thanks

Comment: I'm *guessing* that the problem is with `Festadisticalb_2017` then. I *hope* you aren't storing dates as a `varchar`.

Comment: In the function the params are as `datetime`. Thanks.

Comment: Also, why does it work when I execute the same query in the sql management studio? Thanks.

Comment: Just cause the parameters are doesn't mean the columns are. But still, with a way to replicate the problem, and the SQL for the function, we can't help you.

Comment: What do you need? I'm using the query written above, and `pool.request().query(queryreppedidos)` that's it.

Comment: I even tried using `CONVERT` and `CAST`

Comment: Also tried `.input("inidate", mssql.DateTime, date)` and it doesn't work.

Comment: in case anyone wants to know how did I solve this problem I had to do the task with python.